# Probability of arranging a digit greater than 3,000,000 giving 7 digit options

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

A 7 digit number is formed by arranging the digits 1,2,2,3,6,6,6. What is the probability the number formed is larger than 3,000,000?

Can someone tell me if my approach makes sense/and or is correct.

So in order to be greater than 3,000,000 the first digit needs to be a 3,6,6,6 so there are 4 options for the first spot and then count down for the rest so 4x6x5x4x3x2x1 then for all total arrangements that would be 7! so the probability is 2880/5040. Is that correct?

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: No...because there are duplicates involved.  Say the first digit is $3$.  Then there are six slots left...first place the sixes, $\binom 63$ ways to do that.  Then place the twos, $\binom 32$ ways to do that.  And so on.

Answer (score 1):

You would be correct if the digits were painted colors and you thought a number with a blue $6$ in the millions place was different from a number with a red $6$.  As they are not painted, you need to divide by the number of ways to rearrange the $2$s and $6$s to get the same number.  If we were just asked the number of numbers we could form from $1,1,2$ it is only $3$, not $6$.

A simpler approach is to note that you get a number larger than $3,000,000$ any time the first digit is $3$ or $6$.  That is four digits out of seven.

Comment: so can I divide my total arrangements of 5040 by 3! 2!?

Comment: or would I need to divide the numerator by that same amount as well because doubles can also occur there

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but see my update.

Comment: so the answer would just be 7C4=35 for the number of times the digit is greater than 3,000,000? but when I divide 2880 by 3!2! I still get 240 times?

Comment: To count the number of seven digit numbers you divide both $2880$ and $5040$ by $3!2!$, that is correct.  I don't know what you are saying with $7C4$.  I was just picking one first digit out of the collection, which is $3$ or greater $\frac 47$ of the time.

Answer (score 1):

The total number of numbers equals:$$\frac{7!}{1!2!1!3!}$$

The number of numbers that have $6$ as first digit equals:$$\frac{6!}{1!2!1!2!}$$

The number of numbers that have $3$ as first digit equals:$$\frac{6!}{1!2!0!3!}$$

If every number has equal probability to occur then:$$\left(\frac{6!}{1!2!1!2!}+\frac{6!}{1!2!0!3!}\right)/\frac{7!}{1!2!1!3!}=\frac47$$ is the probability that a number is formed that starts with $3$ or $6$, i.e. exceeds $3000000$.

---

There is a shorter route to this result.

If one of the numbers is randomly chosen then the probability that its first digit will be a $6$ or a $3$ is $\frac47$ since exactly $4$ of the $7$ digits will belong to $\{3,6\}$.